# How to execute a 'command with arguments' on a container of 'multi-container pod'?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have an app/pod: `app1` with 2 containers `service1` and `service2`. These services writes log at /var/log/app1Service1.log and /var/log/aapp1Service2.log. I'd like to tail log from mac's cli. Tried as below but did not work.

```
~ $ kubectl exec app1-6f6749ccdd-4ktwf -c app1Service1 "tail -f -n +1 /var/log/app1Service1.log"
rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"tail -f -n +1 /var/log/app1Service1.log\": stat tail -f -n +1 /var/log/app1Service1.log: no such file or directory"

command terminated with exit code 126
~ $
```

below command works:

```
kubectl exec app1-6f6749ccdd-4ktwf -c app1Service1 ls
kubectl exec app1-6f6749ccdd-4ktwf -c app1Service1 "ls"
```

Seeing failures when I pass arguments to command.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `bash -c` or if your container has `sh` then add `sh -c`

```
kubectl exec app1-6f6749ccdd-4ktwf -c app1Service1 -- bash -c "tail -f -n +1 /var/log/app1Service1.log"
```

Hope this'll help

Comment: Thanks, that worked. It work without `bash -c ` as well. I'm missing `--` between command and container name.

Comment: @Abu Hanifa what is meaning of "-c" here.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, login into the container by running the below cmd
`kubectl exec -it app1-6f6749ccdd-4ktwf -c app1Service1 bash`

Now you are inside the container, check if the file exists and execute `tail -f  /var/log/app1Service1.log`

Comment: Thanks, looking for a way to run from CLI as asked.